# Do any minhagim use Psalm 45 during chuppah?

Tags: minhag, tehilim-psalms, wedding

I know that many Ashkenazi communities of the community use Psalm 128 during the chuppah ceremony. However, there is a Psalm 45 that expresses the joy of marriage no less. I heard that some use it at the entrance of the bride and groom.

Is there such a minhag? Is this Psalm still used in any way during a wedding?